# CFDocument Images

Tags: coldfusion, cfdocument

I am having a problem displaying images within `cfdocument`. I have tried several different options without luck (please see test code below).

It seems that `cfdocument` recognizes there is an image file there, because the size of the table cell changes. Yet still it doesn't display content of the image.
I would appreciate any help.

```
    <cfdocument format="PDF" localURL = "yes">
    <p style="background-color:#006633">

    <table border="1">
    <tr><td><cfoutput>
            output from "file:///#ExpandPath('CEUCertificate_ABondy3.jpg')#" 
            </cfoutput>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color:white">
        <cfoutput>
           <image src="file:///#ExpandPath('CEUCertificate_ABondy3.jpg')#"> 
        </cfoutput>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><cfoutput> output from #ExpandPath('CEUCertificate_ABondy3.jpg')#  </cfoutput> </td>
        <td>
        <cfoutput>
            <image src="#ExpandPath('CEUCertificate_ABondy3.jpg')#"> 
        </cfoutput>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td style="background-color:red">
            Output from: img src="CEUCertificate_ABondy3.jpg"
        </td>
        <td style="background-color:red"> 
            <img src="CEUCertificate_ABondy3.jpg"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:white">
            output from image src="CEUCertificate_ABondy3.jpg"
        </td>
        <td>
            <cfoutput>
            <image src="CEUCertificate_ABondy3.jpg">
            </cfoutput>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Output from local url</td>
        <td>
             <cfoutput>
             <img src=#localUrl("CEUCertificate_ABondy3.jpg")#>
             </cfoutput>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </p>
    </cfdocument>

    <cffunction name="localUrl" >
      <cfargument name="file" />

      <cfset var fpath = ExpandPath(file)>
      <cfset var f="">
      <cfset f = createObject("java", "java.io.File")>
      <cfset f.init(fpath)>

      <cfreturn f.toUrl().toString()>
    </cffunction>
```

Comment: What happens if you use `<img src="/cde/mobileweb/CEUCertificate_ABondy3.jpg"/>` ?

Comment: How much ram have you allocated to the CF instance?  Have you tried increasing it?

Comment: Henry, I don't have control over it.

Answer (score 1):

For your initial question, you need to reference the images in your `cfdocument` tag as you would with any other HTML page; `<img src="url-to-the-image" />`.  So this should work for you.

```
<img src="/cde/mobileweb/CEUCertificate_ABondy3.jpg"/>
```

Now that you have made that change the page is timing out.  This is probably due to how the image was created.  [See this page here](http://coldfused.blogspot.com/2007/12/images-and-cfdocument-performance.html).  Which I found from [Charlie's page here](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2011/11/19/perf_fix_via_cfdocument_localurl_attribute).

Try opening that image in an editor and re-saving it. Then see if the processing time decreases.

I found some more discussion about this on [Ben Nadel's blog here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1949-The-Content-Of-This-Document-Process-Takes-More-Than-60000-Milliseconds-To-Process.htm).

Comment: Thanks! I tried to resave and even resize it already, but I will try again with different editor.

Comment: I wasn't able to make it work. 
I used mpdf library to create pdf.

Comment: If you found another solution to your problem please post it as an answer to the question so that others can find it more easily than in these comments. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing with `ExpandPath()` and `file://`, code it as a normal html and make sure it works first.  Then use `localUrl="true"` in your `<cfdocument>`

Comment: It's used in my code too.  
<img src="CEUCertificate_ABondy3.jpg"/>
Nothing shows up.

Comment: @JanuszChudzynski that is because of how `cfdocument` works with images. Your code is looking for the image in the web root and it is not there. Did you try the example from my comment?

Comment: Yes. And I am getting the following error:
The content of this document process takes more than 60000 milliseconds to process.

Comment: Which is a sign of progress... at least cfdocument seems to process something.

Comment: Are you running additional code than what you shared with us?